# Zero crossing count vs zero crossing rate: does it make any difference?

Tags: audio, feedback

I am trying to make a feedback howling detection program for an audio DSP chip

I made a very crude one by counting zero crossings, doing something like this:

```
for (n = 1; n < NUM_OF_SAMPLES; n++){
   if( (sample_array_int32[n-1] < 0 && sample_array_int32[n] >= 0) || (sample_array_int32[n-1] >= 0 && sample_array_int32[n] < 0) ){
   // zero crossing detected
   zeroCrossCount++; 
   }
}
```

I then compare this count to some threshold and assume feedback is present if it is crossed. The actual zero crossing counter number varies in every situation, but in a noise free room this sort of works, but I also found it detected a lot of false positives like speech being classified as feedback howling, so I abandoned this method

After some more searching I am thinking of going back to this method and use it together with some other techniques, but I have also found that most references recommend using zero crossing rate which is defined by `zero_crossing_number/(2*frame_size)`

My questions are the following:

1. does it make a difference if I use zero crossing count or zero crossing rate as my basis for classification (which will only be comparing against a threshold for now, nothing very fancy, and threshold value will be determined empirically through multiple trial and error experiments)? As far as I understand zero crossing rate is just a division by a constant so does it really give any different information from what I would have got just keeping track of the zero crossing count?
2. Why is there a division by 2 in he zero crossing rate formula? `(Number_of_zeor_crosses)/(Number_of_audio_samples_considered)` seems to make sense as rate of zero crossings. But why does it have the divide by 2?

Comment: I've seen a lot of algorithms for acoustic feedback mitigation but never one that counted zero-crossings (which is notoriously unreliable in acoustic situations anyway) . Can you explain how your algorithms is supposed to work and what the requirements for zero crossing detection are ?

Comment: @Hilmar I'm looking into it at the moment this was just one of the different things I am trying out. I have another algorithm that checks the energy levels at different frequencies after FFT and detects presence of feedback based on some threshold level comparison. It works much better but there are some cases where I can hear a feedback tone but my program does not detect it as such. I am just looking into whether also taking zero crossing count/rate into consideration gives any better result

Answer (score 1):

1. It only makes a difference if your window length changes. ZCR in that sense is more versatile than ZCC because it can be used across audio segments of different lengths.
2. The only thing I can think of for the factor $2$ is that it would be for averaging over both positive-to-negative and negative-to-positive transitions or some other domain-specific normalization.